# Fiddler does not capture network calls from Java process?

Tags: java, fiddler

Read many articles which recommends to set following system properties -

```
System.setProperty("proxySet", "true");
System.setProperty("proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("proxyPort", "8888");
```

Or

Setting using Java VM arguments "-DproxyHost=127.0.0.1 -DproxyPort=8888"

Both the approaches does not make the network calls captured :(

Comment: Using Fiddler v4.4.5.8

Comment: Check Fiddler options and make sure the Fiddler Listens on port is the same number as your own port

Comment: Yep, Fiddler listens to port 8888.

Comment: Just to make sure, does Fiddler capture other network traffic for you?

Comment: It perfectly captures HTTP requests made from browsers. None of the non-browser network calls are traced.

Comment: So it could be other non-browser sources of network traffic besides your Java app that aren't captured? Just trying to determine if it's actually your Java app or something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try this**

```
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8888");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8888");
```

http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureJavaApp

**EDIT**

Okay in my Fiddler option the

**General Tab**
everything is ticked except Enable high Resoulution themes

**Https Tab** 
Everything is ticked and and the drop down box its from all process

**Connection Tab** my port is 8888 and everything is ticked except  Use PaC Script and Capture Ftp Request

**Gateway tab** 
the only think ticked is Autonmatically detect Proxy using Wpad

**Appearance Tab** 
only Use Smart Scroll is clicked

**Extension Tab**
 Automatically Reload Script when Changed is clicked/ticked

Also make Sure in the **File** option click **Capture Traffic** to on. if its on already b4 then switch it off

Comment: I've referred this documentation before asking question here. This settings doesn't work for me.

Comment: Have you tried using v2.4.5.0 or Fiddler 2.. Maybe your firewall is blocking it

Comment: Am using Fiddler 2 maybe i can help with my own settings

Comment: I initially tried v2.x.x and upgraded to v4 as it was not working. It would be great if you can share your Fiddler settings.

Comment: I appreciate your help. The settings mentioned still doesn't resolve my issue. I'm accessing a local server (non-https), so firewall not a concern.

Comment: In the network settings in Java control panel is that where u doing this.. why not tick "use browser settings instead".

Comment: i also saw this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620720/fiddler-not-capturing-http-requests-from-java-application?rq=1

check it out

Comment: Looks, it started working now...Restarted Fiddler few times..Still not sure :)

Comment: lol i will add that to my debugging notes restart fiddler few times to see if it works. Thanks for that

Comment: Everyone knows [you turn it off and on again](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8) to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to configure a web-proxy in java, depends on the java API you are using.
By default Fiddler listens to port 8888

see the below sample code:

```
 CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
                              .setProxy(new HttpHost("localhost", 8888))
                              .setXXXX().build();
```

Refer:
https://benfoster.io/blog/proxying-httpclient-requests-through-fiddler/